# how much linear algebra should i know to study machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

I'm new to machine learning but not very new, I know some simple stuffs like K-means clustering and Artificial Neural Nets and Bayesian reasoning. 
I want to learn machine learning with more details so i started reading "Machine Learning : a probabilistic perspective" and i had no problem till i started the chapter "Gaussian Processes" and there i saw a lot of eigen decompositions and how using a diagonal covariance matrix could help not to overfit ... and i have no idea about that. 
so , what should i do ? should i start reading a whole linear algebra book or should i just focus on some topics of linear algebra in order to learn machine learning in a probabilistic way?

thanks

Comment: If you want to know how to use algorithms, the very basics of linear algebra is enough. If you want to actually understand why things are working behind the scenes, and be able to improve things to fit your specific case, I'd say you need a broader algebra and calculus background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear algebra is a cornerstone because everything in machine learning is a vector or a matrix. Dot products, distance, matrix factorization, eigenvalues etc. come up all the time.

Source: http://fastml.com/math-for-machine-learning/

Answer (score 2):

**Matrix** must become your new first name.

Seriously, a lot of machine learning these days is pure linear algebra, involving plenty of matrix operations. Without sound knowledge in linear algebra, you will find it hard to understand what they are writing; but matrix notation allows putting a whole lot of complexity into a short, *precise*, formula.

Deep learning works well using GPU cards, because it's lots and lots and lots of matrix multiplications. No linear algebra, no deep learning.